# Read a csv data file and return one specific StudentID marks for all their modules in Java

Tags: java, csv

at the moment I have this:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class StudentID {

  public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{

   System.out.println ("Please enter StudentID: ");
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("CW2_data.csv"));
      File file = new File("CW2_data.csv");
 try {
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(
                        new FileInputStream("CW2_data.csv")));
    String line;
    while((line = r.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(line);
    r.close();
} catch(IOException e) {
    System.out.println(" There was an Error Reading the file. " + e.getMessage());
}


  }
}
```

I am trying to get the program to prompt the user for its StudentID, then search through the data file for that StudentId and return their marks for all the modules. Unfortunatly all my codes does is list the whole file back to me.

I tried to add `StudetnID=Userinput.readstring;` right after so that user was given an opertunity to type in the username but then I realise that wouldn't work unless I tell it scan the whole document for it. I was reading up on maps (as recomendeded by user on here) but I still haven't got to grips with it and I don't know if it would it even work here. The data file is in form of 3 columns and about 282 rows of data, ie

```
UserID: Module: Mark

ab006, GYH095, 56
```

Any help would appreciated.

Comment: Its more of an assignment, I am not asking someone to complete for me, just point me good direction that will help me. Something to read and follow

Comment: If you get something that is assigned to you for a class please mark it with the "homework" tag. I've done that for you, but please do that in the future. These questions are heavily indexed on Google and can be easily found via google.

Comment: Also, it looks like you create a `BufferedReader reader` and a `File file` and never use them.

Comment: Yeah I was trying to do something and should of got rid of it

Answer (score 1):

As that this appears to be homework (and how it relates to your previous question) I will not give a full solution.

The buffered reader reads an entire line of text. So you'll get strings similar to this: 
"ab006, GYH095, 56"

With that string you can use something like StringTokenizer or String.split to seperate the individual elements, which now become "ab06", "GYH095", "56" ...

The reason this program just writes the entire file back to you is that the program just scans through the file, without doing anything to what it reads.

Comment: I see so after I have buffered reader the entrie line of text, String.split would sperate the elements, then I could maniuplate them afterwards. are their any examples/reading I could look at that have both of them working together?

Comment: When you use BufferedReader::readLine, it will give you the current line in the form of a string. You can choose to work with the string after it is read and move on or you could choose to store all of it and then work with the entire contents later. I would highly suggest working with it after it is read.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is good progress that you are getting the file to be read properly. What you first want to do is get the user's input before reading the file. This can be done with the Java [Scanner](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class. Take a look there for examples on how to use it (you will want to read a String from the user. Hint: the `nextLine()` method). The rest can be done via stevens explanation.

Comment: Thanks, that has helped, it so obvious that I should of asked the user for the input so I could proceeed, I will hopefully post up what I have done soon.

Comment: im little a bit stuck on the searching of the file for the studentID, I posted up what did, not including the buffereread thing since all I manage to do is return the list

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To load the data, how about you make a simple class that represents a line from your datafile, and then store it in a `List`. Yes, you'll have to scan through the entire list each time but it doesn't seem that large anyway (if there is a natural key you can use, which appears to be the case, you could indeed use a `Map`). Check out the [java tutorial on collections](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/collections/index.html).